# Removing https:// and .com from String

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert a group of given URLs to another format I'll need in another part of the application.

So for the string https://www.myUrl.com/research/case-studies I need the following output:

```
myUrl/research/case studies
```

The following function I created manages just fine but I cannot help feeling I'm not being efficient enough by doing everything in just one line.

```
   function generate_conversion(convert_input, url_format){
      simple_urls = [];
      var new_url = '';
      $.each(convert_input, function(index, item) {
        new_url =  item.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?:\.[a-z\.]+[\/]?)?/,'');
        new_url =  new_url.replace(/([.]\w+)$/, '');
        new_url =  new_url.replace(/.com/g, '');
        simple_urls.push(new_url.replace(/-/g, ' '));
      });

      console.log(simple_urls);

    }
```

Is there a more efficient or readable way to achieve the same result? I cannot use `window.location.host` or similar methods because the URLs are passed as simple strings.

Comment: `var url = new URL('https://www.myurl.com/research/case-studies'); alert(url.host.replace(/www\.|\.com/gi, '') + url.pathname);`

Comment: @Tushar This works like a charm! I did made a mistake editing my post though. For example in case-studies it should instead replace the hyphen for a space so it reads: myUrl/research/case studies

If you can assist me with that fix and post it I'll gladly accept it like the answer.

Comment: Just change last part to `url.pathname.replace(/-/g, ' ')`

Comment: @Tushar that did it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Does the URL always starts with protocol(https, http, etc.)?

Comment: @Tushar there will always be one of two variations:

`https://www.site/item/case-studies` or `http://author.site/item/case-studies`

Answer (score 0):

depends on my understanding try this.,

```
var originalString="https://www.myUrl.com/research/case-studies";
var replacedString=originalString.replace("https://www.","")
console.log(replacedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
var str = "https://www.myUrl.com/research/case-studies";
var simple_url = str.substring(str.indexOf("www.")+4);
console.log(simple_url);
```

Comment: here 4 is the length of "www."

Comment: Problem is that this doesn't cover the eventuality of a http case doesn't it? I wanted regEx because I foresee a case where www will be replaced by author for testing purposes.